# Inserting an attribute to hash in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-4

I am producing a hash "message" containing Message attributes like this:

```
  message = Message.create_from_mail_message(mail, @current_sender_email, expires_at, public, message_type)
```

Now I want to add  an additional attribute "access_key" to this hash "message" problem is this attribute is not in Message model but in Receipt. Any idea about how to do this.

Right now message hash returns me this :

```
{"active":1,"body":"","created_at":"2013-10-30T10:49:41Z","creator_id":6,"expires_at":"2013-11-29T10:49:41Z","id":25,"message_type_id":1,"public":0,"reply_to":null,"slug":"fa2fd66f-7e32-4e3f-898b-8412c676a0ff","subject":"2af03892533ffb43\ufffdh\ufffdf\ufffdS+9<\b&\u0017\ufffd\u0016/\ufffd","updated_at":"2013-10-30T10:49:41Z"}
```

"access_key" can be retrieve by:

```
     access_key = Reciept.access_key
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You should merge the access_key with value in message hash like:

message.merge!("access_key" => Reciept.access_key)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
message.merge!('access_key' => Reciept.access_key)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
message.merge!{access_key: Reciept.access_key}
```

Answer (score 0):

the Standar say:

```
message.merge(:access_key=>Reciept.access_key)
```

I hope can i help you.